# Mixing jQuery based plugin with angular.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I'm refreshing a website that uses the [cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) plugin.

The current version of the app uses jQuery to proceed to an ajax image upload.

Since I'm using angular.js to handle other forms submission I was wondering if I should change the way the image is uploaded too, or if it is disadvised to mix jquery ajax requests along with angular.

What should I do ?

Comment: It is all javascript, and can be made to work together. However, doing things the 'Angular way' does not usually include using jQuery (Although angularjs does include jqlite).

Answer (score 0):

Angular has its own method to make ajax requests. Is the image upload adding the image to the angular form submission? If so then use `$scope.$apply()` in the jQuery ajax response callback so Angular will digest cycle the form change of the uploaded image.

Comment: No it doesn't. Do you mean I should add the image to the scope and let angular doing everything ?